# Database analysis/visualization tool for a document database

Tags: database, graphs, data-analysis, database-browser

I need a tool which could be used for **a simple data-source analysis** by non-tech users.

User story:
User X wants to display his last weeks deliveries grouped by manufacturer as a graph. He can achieve this via an app on our corporate website.

---

Req:

- The tool should be a web-app with its server part being able to run on Linux.
- On-prem only - data can't go to a cloud!
- The tool should be multi-user since every user should be able to access a defined data-source only.
- The tool should allow to create queries *by UI* (filtering, grouping, etc. w/o need for native queries).
- The tool has to work with *document-based data-sources* (MongoDB, Elasticsearch, etc.)
- The tool should be able to display query results as: *tables* and *graph(s)*.
- The tool should be able to display/hint the most common values for given field (my data-source got a table with columns - display 5 most common values).
- The tool has to be customizable/skinable to fit CI.
- It would be nice, if the tool allows a SSO integration (*OpenID*, etc.)
- OSS tools are preferred :)

---

Tools which are similar but don't fit for all the given points:

- Kibana + Elasticsearch
- Graylog 2 + Elasticsearch (this is quite close, but SSO)
- Metabase + MongoDB (this is quite close, but SSO and common values)
- Grafana + Elasticserach
- Graphite
- Re:dash + Elasticsearch
- Tableau + ? (not sure about the data security and a document-based data soruce)